# TCP doesn't work for me in UWP with ngrok reverse proxy

Tags: c#, tcp, uwp, ngrok

I've been making a client server system (client and server are different devices) connected through sockets using TCP. Both the client and server are UWP apps written in C#.

Everything worked well when I established the connection directly using IPv6 address, but then I tried to set up Ngrok in case the user doesn't have IPv6 and doesn't want to or is unable to set up port forwarding. The data wasn't coming through.

I also tested it on a simple program from some tutorial, but it still didn't work. However when I tried to run the same program as a console app everything worked fine. So the UWP is probably somehow blocking the TCP traffic.

- UWP capabilities enabled: **Internet (Client & Server)**, **Private Networks (Client & Server)**
- The client and server are on different devices and loopback is enabled anyway
- I am confused, why the direct connection through IPv6, but not indirectly through Ngrok.

The code used is quite simple, so probably no problem there (taken from a tutorial)

**Server:**

```cs
socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp); 
socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 42222));
socket.Listen(1);

Socket accepteddata = socket.Accept();
data = new byte[accepteddata.SendBufferSize];
int j = accepteddata.Receive(data);
byte[] adata = new byte[j];
for (int i = 0; i < j; i++)
    adata[i] = data[i];
string dat = Encoding.Default.GetString(adata);
Debug.WriteLine(dat);
```

**Client:**

```cs
Socket s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
try {
    s.Connect(IPAddress.Parse("Ngrok Endpoint IP Address"), NgrokPort);
    Console.Write("Enter some text: ");
    string q = Console.ReadLine();
    byte[] data = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(q);
    s.Send(data); }
catch {
    Debug.WriteLine("Unable to connect or send data");
}
```

Everything worked fine in a console app, but not with UWP (no errors, the data was sent, but none of it was received by the server).

I am probably missing something obvious (probably some setting), but I wasn't able to find out what.

Comment: You seem to be using the `System.Net.Sockets`, have you tried using UWP [StreamSocket](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.sockets.streamsocket?view=winrt-22621)? Here are [the official sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/main/Samples/StreamSocket) for your reference.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I haven't tried StreamSocket, because further down the road the client should be able to run both on Android and Windows (UWP) with Xamarin for graphical interface (maybe I should have mentioned it in the question).

Comment: Nevertheless I will give StreamSockets a try and hopefully get some insight that way.